# Issue regarding upgrading & uploading Phonegap IOS Application to the itune app store (64-bit & IOS 8 requirements)

Tags: cordova, ios8, 64-bit, phonegap-plugins

I have phonegap IOS app using 2.9 cordova , i want to upgrade my App regarding 64-bit & IOS 8 requirements. so I need to create new app then deploy all of my code to in it or can i upgrade my existing app. Plzz help & tell me the easiest way to do it.

Comment: ... so setting up a new project with copying the old files will cost you two minutes. Registering here, writing your question took you at least 5 minutes. Why don't you just try out? Set up a new one, copy your files, thats all. Our you update your cordova globally `sudo npm update -g cordova` and update the platforms you want to update after that with `cordova platform update android`

Comment: as he is on 2.9 he can't update with cordova platform update, but yes, creating a new project is the easiest and faster way of updating an old project